# in mysql, how to delete elements in json array that don't contain certain string values?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-json

I have table with a column of jsons that have example value:

```
{"name": "1", "list": ["abc", "xyz"]}
{"name": "2", "list": ["b", "bc", "bcd"]}
{"name": "3", "list": ["cd", "cdef", "def", "defg", "ef"]}
```

I also have a array of (sub)strings that I want to keep in the array, for example:
`["a","bc","def"]`
(in my reality, about 20 strings)

How do I update the table so that only elements of the list that contain at least one of the strings remain?

expected result:

```
{"name": "1", "list": ["abc"]}
{"name": "2", "list": ["bc", "bcd"]}
{"name": "3", "list": ["cdef", "def", "defg"]}
```

honestly, i have no clue where to even begin, or even if it's possible in sql with its json functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6iMS7ThhBvenZrFdz4ZwbA/0) is an example. The idea is to split the values from the `list` arrays and check for matches using `REGEXP`. Then build new `list` arrays containing only the matched elements. After that, update the original table.

```
CREATE TABLE DataSource 
( 
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
   ,RawData JSON
);

INSERT INTO DataSource (RawData) VALUES 
    ('{"name": "1", "list": ["abc", "xyz"]}'),
    ('{"name": "2", "list": ["b", "bc", "bcd"]}'),
    ('{"name": "3", "list": ["cd", "cdef", "def", "defg", "ef"]}');

SET @keepList = '["a","bc","def"]';
SET @keepList = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@keepList, '[', ''), ']', ''), ',', '|'), '"', '');

WITH NewDataSource (ID, name, value) AS
(
      SELECT DS.ID
            ,JSON_EXTRACT(DS.RawData, '$.name')
            ,JSON_ARRAYAGG(j.value)
      FROM DataSource DS,
      JSON_TABLE(DS.RawData, '$.list[*]' COLUMNS (value VARCHAR(255) PATH '$')) AS j
      WHERE j.value REGEXP  @keepList
      GROUP BY DS.ID
              ,JSON_EXTRACT(DS.RawData, '$.name')
 ) 
UPDATE DataSource T
INNER JOIN NewDataSource S
    ON T.id = S.id
SET T.RawData = JSON_OBJECT
               (
                  'name', S.name
                 ,'list', S.value
               );
               
SELECT *
FROM DataSource;
```

[image]